# How to use Eloquent ORM with PDO ODBC SQLServer Laravel5 Framework

Tags: sql-server, laravel-5, eloquent, pdo-odbc

I'm trying to do a query to retrieve all users using eloquent ORM laravel5 PDO ODBC connection and when tray to do this

```
$email = "myemail@domain.com";
$data = Users::where('email',$email)->get();
```

I get this error

```
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 402 [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the equal to operator. (SQLExecute[402] at /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_php/php56-odbc/work/php-5.6.19/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254) (SQL: select * from \"Users\" where \"email\" = 'myemail@domain.com')"
```

as you see I'm using FreeTDS to connect with SQL Server, I don't know if this driver needs an aditional configuration or I have to modify laravel core.

In this error the main problem is `\"Users\" and \"email\"` backslash and quotation marks around `Users` and `email`. How can I remove this quotation marks and why laravel is doing this.

however if I try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE email = 'myemail@domain.com'";
$return = DB::select(DB::raw($sql));
```

it works perfectly, but I think this isn't the better way to build queries in laravel.

User model screenshot
[image: User model screenshot]

---

FYI

I'm using laravel 5 on Mac OS X EL Capitan, MAMP Server, php 5.6.10, pdo-odbc

Comment: Are you printing the data itself? I mean, you're not returning a view with that data?

Comment: I'm returning json data, but I need run the query first

Comment: Have you seen the SQL generated by Eloquent when working with the Users model?

Comment: Yes, it's in the second block of code. 
`(SQL: select * from \"Users\" where \"email\" = 'myemail@domain.com')"`

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your User model definition? Just to make sure it's okay

Comment: Which driver are you using for the odbc connection? sqlsrv?

Comment: I'm using FreeTDS, looks like is working perfectly but not with Eloquent @Jeemusu